# PHP: Image not save in server folder and database (as URL)

Tags: php, mysql

Currently, I created a PHP system that can allow the user to upload a photo. Now, I get this error.

PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(images/before_4.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tgotworker_testing\pages\dashboard\engineer\view_task\update_photo_before.php on line 28
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\phpA952.tmp' to 'images/before_4.png' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tgotworker_testing\pages\dashboard\engineer\view_task\update_photo_before.php on line 28

Below is my code.

```
<?php

    require_once '../../../../config/configPDO.php';

    $report_id = $_POST['report_id'];
    $last_insert_id = null;

    //Allowed file type
    $allowed_extensions = array("jpg","jpeg","png");

    //File extension
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['uploadFile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    //Check extension
    if(in_array($ext, $allowed_extensions)) {

        $defID = "before_" . $report_id;
        $imgPath = "images/$defID.png";
        $ServerURL = "http://172.20.0.45/tgotworker_testing/android/$imgPath";

        $query = "UPDATE ot_report SET photo_before = '$ServerURL', time_photo_before = GETDATE() WHERE report_id = :report_id";
        $sql = $conn->prepare($query);
        $sql->bindParam(':report_id', $report_id);
        $sql->execute();

        if ($sql){

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'], $imgPath); //line 28
            echo "<script>alert('Saved')</script>";
            header("Location: view_task.php?report_id=".$_POST['report_id']);

        }else{
            echo "Error!! Not Saved";
        }


    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('File not allowed')</script>";
        header("Location: view_task.php?report_id=".$_POST['report_id']);    

    }

?>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Why encode the uploaded file via base64 and then using `file_put_contents()` to save the base64 decoded data instead of `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'], $imgPath);`?

Also I would suggest to use an ***absolute*** path instead of an ***relative*** path for destination!

Comment: @CodyKL, thanks for your reply. but I seem don't understand. Can you edit my code above?

Comment: 1. Just remove the line `$photo_before = base64_encode(...`. 2. Replace `file_put_contents(....)` with the function `move_uploaded_file(....)`.

Comment: @CodyKL already update my code as above. I also got error. you can also refer the error above

Comment: You are still using `file_get_contents()`! Remove this, you don't need it there! `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'], $imgPath);`

Comment: @CodyKL, still failed. already edited

Comment: If you still get an error show the related error you get now!

Comment: @CodyKL. Done!! Please check my latest edited question above !! Thanks!

Comment: The destination path does not exists! Make sure your destination path where you want to save the file is correct. Use *absolute* path!

Comment: @CodyKL can uo give the example !!!!! Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using file_get_contents() on this line 28 :

```php
move_uploaded_file(file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadFile']['name']),$imgPath);
```

but the function move_uploaded_file is not needing the result of it. You can just do like that instead :

```php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'],$imgPath);
```

For your second problem with absolute path:
in $imgPath maybe you should use this instead:

```php
$imgPath="C:/inetpub/wwwroot/tgotworker_testing/android/images/$defID.png";
```